# How to search the value from table with a static value

Tags: laravel

I am successfully searching the absolute values from the table. When I am searching with value like "4", then the result is showing.
Here is my code in Model:

```
public static function scopeSearch($query, $searchTerm)
    {
        return $query->where('experience', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchTerm . '%');
    }
```

Currently, I am fetching the value `4` from the table. Also, I have a static value i.e. `years`. Now, I just want that when I search with `4 years` then it will also show the result of 4.
Is it possible to add the static value like years while searching.
If possible, please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first explode `$searchTerm` by space and then use orWhere with like.

in your model first make `cities` relationship something like this i don't know your exact structure:

```
public function cities()
{
    return $this->hasMany(City::class,'job_id','city');
}
```

then use it in query like this:

```
public static function scopeSearch($query, $searchTerm)
{

    if(!is_null($searchTerm)){
        $words = explode(' ',$searchTerm);
        return $query->Where(function ($q) use($words) {
            foreach ($words as $word){
                $q->orwhere('experience', 'like',  '%' . $word .'%');
            }
        })->orWhere(function ($q) use($words) {
            foreach ($words as $word){
                $q->orwhere('job_title', 'like',  '%' . $word .'%');
            }
        })->orWhere(function ($q) use($words) {
            $q->WhereHas('cities',function ($qe) use($words) {
                foreach ($words as $word){
                    $qe->orwhere('cities.city', 'like',  '%' . $word .'%');
                }
            });
        });
    }else{
        return $query->Where('experience','');
    }
}
```

i think there are better solutions but this is what i found for now.

Comment: you should better use relations instead of raw query

Comment: ok, I will check for it as I am new in Laravel. Can you please check in my code, it is possible in it or not. Is it possible ?

Comment: i don't know try it if worked then it is possible :)

Comment: In above code, it shows the error, `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cname' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `jobs` where ((`experience` like %4%) or (`job_title` like %4%) or (`cname` like %4%))`

Comment: Little error in it, `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cities.job_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `jobs` where ((`experience` like %mis%) or (`job_title` like %mis%) or (exists (select * from `cities` where `jobs`.`id` = `cities`.`job_id` or (`cities`.`city` like %mis%))))`

Comment: this query `select * from cities where jobs.id = cities.job_id` will must be `select * from cities where jobs.city= cities.id`

Comment: thankyou, its working. But, when I search without entering anything, its still showing the result

Comment: last query i.e. of cities is not working, can you please check, its showing all the results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224359/discussion-between-babak-asadzadeh-and-bhawesh-bhakar).